# Add a contentEditable=true to every 2nd TD on Button Click wit jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick, contenteditable

I have a table like this:

```
    <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 30%;">Fon:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 30%;">Fax:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td style="width: 30%;">E-Mail:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

How can I add a contenEditable=true to every 2nd td on button click with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like,

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $("table > tbody > tr > td:last-child").attr("contentEditable","true");
});
```

Since the `td` element that you are targeting is a last child you could use `:last-child` selector at this context. Also `tbody` should be the immediate child of `table` not `tr`.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pbuzjets/1/)

Comment: Ok, that go in the right way, thank you. But the problem is that every TD ist now editable. Is there a way to make only the every second TD editable?

Comment: Yes, the TD with the PHP (in my case)

Comment: Wow, thats awesome. Thank you so much. One little thing. How can I make it only to e specific table with a unique ID? I try to change table to #id but that do not work.

Comment: OK. I got it:  $("#table1 > tbody > tr > td:last-child").attr("contentEditable", "true");

Comment: @DragonStyle Glad to help! :) Try to press the tick mark present inside of this answer, If you feel that this answer has helped you. And that is not a compulsion. :)